# Async/Await to simulate busy server that delay update to client browser

Tags: async-await

MERN noob here. Trying to learn Async/Await by simulating a busy server where client browser only get the update > 3 seconds later (i will manually refresh localhost:3000, after 3 seconds. I only need help on Node.js/ server side for this question)

Could you help rectify codes below? Kindly avoid proposing other ways/methods but show me how to achieve using below example. Thanks in advance.

```
const app = require('express')()

async function getData() { 
    //Purpose: to simulate a busy server that returns data back to browser, after 3 seconds delay  
    await setTimeout(() => {
        return 'After waiting 3 seconds, return this sentense as the required data to the browser.'
    }, 3000);
}

app.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const data = await getData()
        await res.status(200).send(`${data}`)
    } catch (err) {
        await res.status(400).send(`Unable to get data. Error message, "${err}"`)
    }
})

app.listen(3000)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that `setTimeout` doesn't return a promise so you can't use `await` with it. It just executes the given function after 3 seconds. You can get what you want by wrapping it in a Promise like this:

```js
const app = require('express')()

function getData() {
    //Purpose: to simulate a busy server that returns data back to browser, after 3 seconds delay
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve('After waiting 3 seconds, return this sentense as the required data to the browser.');
      }, 3000);
    });
}

app.get('/', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const data = await getData()
        await res.status(200).send(`${data}`)
    } catch (err) {
        await res.status(400).send(`Unable to get data. Error message, "${err}"`)
    }
})

app.listen(3008)
```

Note that you need a `return` statement to return the promise inside of `getData`. You didn't have a return statement originally which means the function returns `undefined` (or if marked as `async` it gives a Promise that resolves to `undefined`).

Here we don't need to use async/await because you're not needing to use `await` until in the `app.get`.  Using async/await in `getData` could be added but it would be redundant.

Realize that `aync`/`await` uses Promises - it's just an easy way to work with Promises. So you can't await on anything but a `Promise`. Note that `async` really just means "this function returns a `Promise` and we'll wrap any result in a `Promise` if it isn't already a `Promise`". So you cannot use `async`/`await` without having a `Promise` at some point.

But if you really want to use `async`/`await` for some reason maybe this example would help you:

```js
async function getData() {
    //Purpose: to simulate a busy server that returns data back to browser, after 3 seconds delay
    const result = await new Promise((resolve) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve('After waiting 3 seconds, return this sentense as the required data to the browser.');
      }, 3000);
    });
    console.log('We are done waiting 3 seconds');
    return result;  // <-- this returns a Promise that resolves to the result string
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to rewrite all in Async/Await (without Promises)? If yes, pls show. Thanks

Comment: aync/await uses Promises - it's just an easy way to work with Promises. So you can't `await` on anything but a Promise. Note that `async` really just means "this function returns a Promise and we'll wrap any result in a Promise if it isn't already a Promise". So you cannot use async/await without having a Promise at some point.